# Node version manager

Tags: node.js, n

I'm trying to install n to downgrade node
it gives me:

`Unsupported platform for n@8.0.0: wanted {"os":"!win32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})`

[image]

If you know how to solve this please let me know.

Comment: read: https://www.npmjs.com/package/n#supported-platforms

Comment: You could use another node version manager which is supported on native Windows, like nvs or nwm-windows. You could download an installer for the older version of node from the nodejs downloads server: https://nodejs.org/dist/ You can use n in WSL to manage a Linux install of node.

What problem are you trying to solve? Downgrading node, or having a node version manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [official doc](https://github.com/tj/n) says:

> `n` does not work in native shells on Microsoft Windows (like PowerShell), or Git for Windows BASH, or with the Cygwin DLL.

So yeah, your **Windows** machine is unsupported.

Comment: Perhaps "Windows shell" rather than "Windows machine"

Comment: what can I do about it?

Comment: Use a different machine. There's nothing else you can do.